# Vimeo videos in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, vimeo

I was wondering if there's a way to "embed" a Vimeo video in an iPhone app.

For YouTube videos I'm using a webview containing the correct embed code for the YouTube video and the iPhone's native YouTube support will then transform the flash player into a YouTube button.

Is there a similar way to play Vimeo videos from my app?

Maybe someone knows the correct `<video>`-src for Vimeo videos?

thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that vimeo is transcoding all videos being uploaded these days into versions compatible for the iphone which are used on their site when you browse from an iphone or ipad. You can however call their videos into an HTML5 player on your site by doing some [simple tricks found here.](http://www.stacyconaway.com/bucket/JS-Vimeo-embed-code-with-notes.pdf) If you can host a page on your site somewhere, you can load the video into a UIWebView and it should all work. Vimeo's only limitation is that there embed code is flash but the video infrastructure is all there for HTML5. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

This is the code to embed the vimeo video in a UIWebview

```
<iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/12345678?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0' width='320' height='480' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

here 12345678 is the video id.

**Sadly my app got rejected for embedding HQ vimeos in a UIWebview in the app.**

Comment: Ah nvm. You were embedding the videos directly. I think you need to do this dynamically, as the iframe src has to be empty.

Comment: Apple said that the video should be streamed using HTTP Live Streaming

Comment: @ArunGJ, have you found any solution to this, so that the app could be approved by Apple?

Comment: @REACHUS No as i said above, HTTP live streaming is the way they said it should be.

Comment: How to play private videos like https://vimeo.com/308189520/c0ace02792
because it's a private video. It's not playing in HTML embed link.
In the embed code only playing public video like https://vimeo.com/129552711
because 129552711 is the id of this video.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible - Vimeo uses flash.

However according to this

http://news.cnet.com/8301-27076_3-10394769-248.html

Some videos in the Vimeo collection have been converted to be playable on mobile devices that don't support flash

Comment: Yeah, but those videos only seem to play when they're requested from the vimeo site...

Answer (score 0):

According to Vimeo forum at the moment the only way is to link to a mobile URL like

```
vimeo.com/m/#/id
```

they say they will add API to search mobile video content
more info on http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:20132

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>"
                                @"<head>"
                                @"<meta name = \"viewport\" content =\"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 320\"/></head>"
                                @"<frameset border=\"0\">"
                                @"<frame src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/%@?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=1&amp;autoplay=1\" width=\"320\" height=\"140\" frameborder=\"0\"></frame>"
                                @"</frameset>"
                                @"</html>", 
                                videoID];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my way of play a Vimeo video inside a app.

I am using iFrame to load Vimeo video inside my app.

follow this steps and you will too.

create a uiwebview and connect it to your .h file. Mine is _webView.

Add this method to your .m file.

```
-(void)embedVimeo{

NSString *embedHTML = @"<iframe width=\"300\" height=\"250\" src=\"http://www.vimeo.com/embed/rOPI5LDo7mg\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML];

[_webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:_webView];
}
```

I am using the embedded code in Vimeo video. (I hope you know what it is)

call this method inside your viewdidload

```
[self embedVimeo];
```

Run the app and you will see the video in your view. This way is perfectly working for me and i think this will help for your too.

Comment: Did you have any issues with app approval from Apple as mentioned by ArunGJ above? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503235/vimeo-videos-in-iphone-app?rq=1#comment12993446_7116617

Comment: Nop didnt get any issue for approving ... yet