# How to embed a Vimeo video in a view?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, vimeo

I have a view in which I want to embed a vimeo video.

Which options do I have to embed a Vimeo videos in a view with as much control over it's look as possible? I don't mind getting a Vimeo+ pro account if that helps.

Comment: You can do it by sub-classing UIWebView and pass the Vimeo video's URL string in WebView's loadHTMLString method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this would help.  [Vimeo videos in iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503235/vimeo-videos-in-iphone-app/7116617#7116617)